# QCompleter показать все значения при пустой QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlineedit, qcompleter

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой задачей. У меня есть QLineEdit, в котором реализован поиск при помощи всплывающего списка QCompleter. Список появляется если в QlineEdit введена хотя бы одна буква(Рис. 1). Мне необходимо реализовать, что если пользователь поставил курсор в QLineEdit, то должны появляться все возможные варианты из QCompliter(Рис 2).

[image: Рисунок 1]
[image: Рисунок 2]

Я Нашел похожий вопрос на С++, там это предлагается сделать при помощи таких методов:

```
my_completer.setCompletionPrefix("")
my_completer.complete()
```

Однако у меня это не работает. Подскажите, как можно реализовать мою задачу?
Код всей программы:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication, QLineEdit, QCompleter

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Текстовая линия
        line1 = QLineEdit(self)
        line1.setGeometry(100,100,200,35)

        # Комплитер
        my_list = ["Apple", "Apartments", "Application"]
        my_completer = QCompleter(my_list)
        line1.setCompleter(my_completer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(450, 200, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо установить фильтр событий и отслеживать получение фокуса вашим инпутом:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication, QLineEdit, QCompleter
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        # Текстовая линия1
        line0 = QLineEdit(self)
        line0.setGeometry(100,50,200,35)

        # Текстовая линия2
        self.line1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line1.setGeometry(100,100,200,35)

        # Комплитер
        my_list = ["Apple", "Apartments", "Application"]
        self.my_completer = QCompleter(my_list)
        self.line1.setCompleter(self.my_completer)
        self.line1.installEventFilter(self) # устанавливаем eventfilter для виджета

    def eventFilter(self, object, event): # фильтр событий 
        if event.type() == QEvent.FocusIn: # если событие - получение фокуса
            if object==self.line1: # если источник события - ваш виджет
                self.my_completer.setCompletionPrefix(self.line1.text())
                self.my_completer.complete()
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(450, 200, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Tatarincev Большое спасибо! Это действительно работает. Благодарен за развернутый ответ.